# Getting value from another component in Angular 10

Tags: angular

I have 2 components called `subscription.ts` and `home.ts`
On subscription I have a functions which checks if user is subscribed or not. The function is as follows

```
checkSubscriptionStatus(): any {

    this.apiService.getSubscriptionStatus().subscribe((getData: any) => {
        this.subsStatus = getData.data.subscription.status;
      },
      error => {
        this.subsStatus = '';
        if (error.status !== 401) {
          this.commonService.showNotificationMessage('Something went wrong. Try again!', 'text-danger');
        }
      });
  }
```

I want to use the value of `this.subsStatus` on the view of `home.ts`, that is on `home.html`. I tried to add `<app-subscription></app-subscription>` which is the component selector for `subscription.ts` but it is showing the whole `subscription.html` view. I just want to use the variable. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a service and inject it.

Comment: Is `subscription` and `home` are parent child component ?

Comment: @SJNF, no. they are separate components

Comment: @MRahi Do you want to make your `subscription` as a service?

Comment: First of all you need to subsStatus variable in commonService then you can use in your home.ts file easily

Comment: After declare variable in commonService then store into direct like this.commonService.subsStatus = getData.data.subscription.status;

Comment: On common.service.ts `export class CommonService {subsStatus;}` and `checkSubscriptionStatus() {this.commonService.subsStatus = getData.data.subscription.status;}` then is used `subsStatus` at home.html but its giving the following error during compilation `Property 'commonService' does not exist on type 'CommonService'. this.commonService.subsStatus = getData.data.subscription.status;`

Comment: @MRahi Please check my code and let me know does it serve your purpose or not. Best wishes. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, I have Two solutions for you, Here is the first one. It is little complex.

**Way 1:** 
Firstly, you can use a middle service which will share data between 2 classes.
The service will look like below=>

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class MyService {
  mystatusChanged: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  mystatus: any;
  constructor() {}
  get data(): any {
    return this.mystatus;
  }
  set data(val: any) {
    this.mystatus = val;
    this.mystatusChanged.emit(val);
  }
}
```

Here, you can a `get` and  `set` method for data. At the same time when data updated an event will emit. So, you can use that service in both `subscription.ts`  and `home.ts` file. In `subscription`file you will set the data of that service inside `checkSubscriptionStatus` function. On the other hand, you have to subscribe the event in the `home.ts` like below=>

**In subscription.ts File:**

```
constructor(private mysrvc:MyService){
    
  }    
checkSubscriptionStatus(): any {
       this.mysrvc.data='Active Status';  //set your status.
     
}
```

**In home.ts File:**

```
constructor(private mysrvc:MyService){
     mysrvc.mystatusChanged.subscribe(status=>this.updatedStatus(status));
}
updatedStatus(status){
    console.log(status);
}
```

Now, the thing is you can call `checkSubscriptionStatus` of by creating a object of  `SubscriptionComponent` and home component will get the updated value.

[Demo Sample Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phz5ck?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

**Way 2:**
You can use `@ViewChild`,`hidden` and `@Output` to achieve it=>

 `subscription.ts`

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'subscription',
  template: `<h1>subscription</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class SubscriptionComponent  {
   @Output() myUpdatedStatus = new EventEmitter<string>();
  checkSubscriptionStatus(){
     this.myUpdatedStatus.emit("Active Status");
  }
}
```

**For home HTML**

```
<subscription #child hidden (myUpdatedStatus)="showStatus($event)"></subscription>
<br><button (click)="myClick()">Click Me!!</button>
<br>
<label>{{status}}</label>
```

**For Home TS:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('child') child:SubscriptionComponent;
  status:any;
  
  showStatus($event){
    console.log($event);
    this.status=$event;
  }
  myClick(){
    this.child.checkSubscriptionStatus();
  }
}
```

[Demo Sample Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n9wwva?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a service to share data across components.

Comment: I am new in NG. Can u please elaborate a bit? Thanks

Comment: Please give an example.